# pentaho report designer: if the value is null, then show a certain string

Tags: pentaho-report-designer

In my DB, some of values of a column (called **status**) are null, and if they are null, I want to show a String "**canceled**". 
Guess I need to do it on `Attributes` - `common` -`if-null` but then don't know how to specify it.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options, as you said, `Attributes` - `common` - `if-null` on the field containing the status should do that, you can specify a String by entering it in the Value box. If your string disappears after unfocusing, click the `...` while the Value entry is selected, that will launch a Popup-entrybox.

Alternatively, you could put that logic into your query

```sql
select coalesce(status, 'Cancelled')
from table
```

> COALESCE
>
> Evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially doesn't evaluate to NULL. For example, SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL, 'third_value', 'fourth_value'); returns the third value because the third value is the first value that isn't null.

Some databases might have similar functions with different names, with Oracle e.g. there's `nvl()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just entered the string I want to show if the value is null on "if-null" and it worked out. Thanks again!